# CACHE infrastructure with WCF services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, caching, service

I have some WCF services(Let's call X) which has a cache service client in it. So that, the end user who calls my WCF service does not know about cache and should not be care about it.

My cache service is also a WCF service which is not publicly avaliable, just X can call it. As you know it is possible to put any kind of object in cache(let's assume that Cache is HttpRuntime.Cache), but when the issue comes in WCF, presenting the cached values from a WCF service, any kind of object could be a problem because of unknown data types.

My questions is, how can I serve my cache values from WCF as could as it can be generic?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't going to solve your issue if you're stuck with this architecture, but personally I'd avoid this set-up completely.

I'd use a dedicated data cache of some sort with a dedicated client that talks to the cache in an efficient way.

If you're not going out-of-process with your caching, then you could use an in-memory cache, otherwise if you're going cross-process, or over the network, you'd be better off using a dedicated data cache like *AppFabric/Velocity* or *Memcached*.

You'd get so many other benefits out-of-the-box too, like distributed caching, redundancy and automatic fail-over.  I doubt WCF is going to be a winning solution for data caching unknown objects.